# build xml tag based on condition without using CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to form a xml element based on the actionCode which can be eithr CREATE or UPDATE

If **actionCode** is create then i need `<v1:createStudent>` ,if it is UPDATE then i need to form `<v1:updateStudent`>.

I can write using CDATA as follows

```
<xsl:if test="$actionCode ='CREATE'">
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
           <![CDATA[<v1:createOrderCheckoutRequest version="1">]]>  
           </xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="$actionCode ='UPDATE'">
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
           <![CDATA[<v1updateOrderCheckoutRequest version="1">]]> 
           </xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
```

With CDATA i have some problems.I need any other solution wothout using CDATA.
            For example see below code

```
      <
    <xsl:if test="$actionCode ='CREATE'">                
     cre
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$actionCode ='UPDATE'">                
        upd
    </xsl:if>
    ateStudent>
```

Comment: Please show us an example of your input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oog.  If you are trying to create an element with a name generated on-the-fly, DON'T attempt to do it by fooling the XSLT processor into writing text that looks like XML.

This is the *one* useful purpose of the `xsl:element` node.  You can construct a variable with the qualified name and use that to name the element.

Sample stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:v1="urn:v1"
  extension-element-prefixes=""
  exclude-result-prefixes="">

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="action"
      select="/indoc/action"/>

    <xsl:variable name="element-name">
      <xsl:text>v1:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$action = 'create'">
          <xsl:text>createNode</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$action = 'update'">
          <xsl:text>updateNode</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>dontKnow</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <outdoc>
      <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
        <contents/>
      </xsl:element>
    </outdoc>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input:

```
<indoc>
  <action>update</action>
</indoc>
```

Sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outdoc xmlns:v1="urn:v1">
  <v1:updateNode>
    <contents/>
  </v1:updateNode>
</outdoc>
```

The nice thing about using `xsl:element` this way is that it is namespace-prefix-aware.  It *knows* that the "v1:" embedded in your variable is associated with urn:v1.